# How to stop words and images from stretching when zooming into site

Tags: html, css

The HTML page I'm working on works okay-ish when I zoom out, but when I zoom in, the paragraphs on the site don't stay within their area, they become lines of words reading up and down instead of left to right and the pictures become too large. If anyone has any idea how to fix this, I would love to know.

Here is the link to my page: tamaricampbell.com (Some of the words are still not Lipsum because I'm still working out the wording, thanks) Hope this helps with understanding what I mean.

Comment: You need to make sure that all of the units you're using are fixed such as pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### because your website lack responsive concept

you need to use `media query` to adjust your content and element as you need

Comment: Thanks for the feed back I'll have to try that. :)

Answer (score 0):

this can work if you mean that font size is getting to big

```
  :root {
  font-size: 1vw;
  }
```